# How do I convert a .bil (and associated .clr, .blw, .hdr, and .stx) files into georeferenced rasters in R? OR to geotiffs using gdal_translate?

Tags: raster, gdal, r, gdal-translate, rgdal

The title says it all.  I've got a bunch of .bil files, which I can open in R using the `raster` command pointed to the path to the .bil file.  But I don't know how to efficiently incorporate the contents of the other files, which seem to be metadata, into the raster layer in order to georeference it.

Alternatively, could I convert these sets of files to geotiffs using a `system()` call to `gdal_translate`?  What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: How about using `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert to geotiff with raster package:

```
input_name=raster("c:/file.bil") #if you use 
output_name="c:/output.tif")
writeRaster(input_name, output_name,format="GTiff",datatype='INT1U',overwrite=TRUE)
```

the data type depends of your input data type, in this case 8bits.

if you want to convert to geotiff with gdalUtils package:

```
gdal_translate(input_name, output_name, ot='INT1U', of = "GTiff")
```

which other software will you use? envi? erdas?